# Visual Studio Code high cpu

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

So a Linux user developing Node.js may decide to use Visual Studio Code 1.1.1.

Once one has installed babel in the project, like 400 MiB of JavaScript, every time you save, vsc hogs one cpu core at 100% for 30 - 80 s. Any activity during this time is horribly slow, like typing or a saving a short file takes 6 s. I suppose vsc is scanning the file system for words to suggest.

1. Can this be configured into a more usable state? [files.watcherExclude](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/vMarch#_workbench) does not help
2. How does one discern what vsc is using all that cpu for?
3. Is vsc not the right tool?
4. Is it this [bug: File watcher resulting in high CPU use on Mac/Linux for large folders #3998](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3998)

Comment: Can you share more details about the folder you are opening Code with? It could be related to file watching but only if the folder is very large. We have a setting to exclude large folders from file watching as you found out.

Comment: Here is the type of project: https://github.com/jamesknelson/webpack-black-triangle

The point is that transpiling means 360 MiB code, 70,000 files

Comment: I think this is fixed by today’s vscode 1.2.1. At least, I no longer have it.